# How to listen for clicks within an action - emberjs best practices

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I have started learning emberjs quite recently and am struggling to get a understanding on how different components interact with each other, as well as the best practices for doing things.

What I am looking to do is use the class binding ember provides to reproduce the following crude jquery functionality:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        showMenu: function() {
            $('.menu-bar').removeClass('hideMenu');
            $('.menu-bar').addClass('showMenu');

        $('.page').click(function() {
            $('.menu-bar').removeClass('showMenu');
            $('.menu-bar').addClass('hideMenu');
        });
    }
}
});
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    showMenu: false,
    actions: {
        showMenu: function() {
            this.set('showMenu', true);
        }
    }
});
```

My menu-bar component looks like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":menu-bar showMenu:menuSlideDown:menuSlideUp"}} {{action 'showMenu'}}>
</div>
```

and finally my template being loaded into {{outlet}} looks like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":page :home :current"}}>
    {{menu-bar}}
    <div class="splash center button-perspective">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know the "best practice" for the required functionality. Also please note I am using ember-cli.

I could add a {{action}} listener on the element 'page' but I have multiple templates with the 'page' class and so would have to add this listener to all the pages - also this means it will trigger every time page is clicked which feels dirty to me. I would like to handle all the actions belonging to my menu-bar.js component inside the menu-bar's controller. Is that sound logic and if yes\no, what is the best way of doing this?

If additional information is required I am happy to provide - also any and all criticism is welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by menu-bar controller? It will change according to the context. Do you mean you want to handle 'showMenu' action in the controller in context?

Comment: Yes I would like to handle my logic in the controller I have provided,  which as far as I understand it,  is the controller of my menu-bar component.

Comment: But thats not right. since you can use component at many places, it should be handled in the respective controller, and there is a way to handle it.

Comment: Are you suggesting I handle it in my templates controller? If I had a 50 page app then I would have to repeat my logic in all the controllers?

Comment: No, I am saying whichever part is common for your component should go to component JS file and if any behaviour which you want to handle specifically in controller of the template then you can sendAction. And one more things,there is no controller file associated with component.

Comment: Ok I think I understand - could you provide an example that does something similar to what I have provided? Also what is the file I mistook for my menu-bars controller used for?

Answer (score 2):

This can be an example to achieve the functionality

```
//In any view template, consider custom-form as a component
{{custom-form dataSet=model.data action='submitForm'}}

//In custom-form.hbs
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
    <span>Form</span>   
    {{#if isExpanded}}
        <span class="arrow"{{action "toggleExpanded"}}><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></span>
    {{else}}
        <span class="arrow" {{action "toggleExpanded"}}><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></i></span>
    {{/if}} 
    </div>  
    {{#if isExpanded}}
        {{#each qObj in dataSet}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{qObj.question}}</label>
            {{input value=qObj}}
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
    <button {{action 'submitForm'}}>Submit</button>
</div>

//In custom-form.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/custom-form';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout: layout,
  isExpanded:true,
  actions:{
    submitForm:function(){
        this.sendAction(); //This will send action to outside application
    },
    toggleExpanded:function(){
        this.toggleProperty('isExpanded');
    }
  }
});


//In any controller which is the context of component
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions:{
        submitForm:function(){
            alert('From Controller');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.get('model.data')));
        }
    }
});
```

Now here action='submitForm' is defined, this method name can be any name which you would be implementing in your controller, if you want to handle some specific functionality on the basis of components action.
And normal actions of components would be handled inside the component only, like `'toggleExpanded'` and `'submitForm'` . Now to send an action from component to application, use `sendAction` method.

Now files related to components would be only in templates/componets/*.hbs and components/*.js

Comment: This does not answer my question. You are only toggling the isExpanded class to false when a link on the custom component is clicked. What I am requiring is when I click anywhere that is not the component, it toggles off. However handling this action from outside controllers with the sendAction() method becomes messy. So how would I go about doing this.

Comment: I have shown you a example copy which I had, just see submitForm action which is handled in component, and there you can handle you javascript functionality. And if you want outside application to know something related to your action then use sendAction(). Now to handle the case you mentioned, you should pass a property to component, when you click some outside view, then toggle that property, it will automatically reflects the changes in component through property you have binded.

Comment: Am I able to send the property to my component with a handlebars helper?

Comment: yes, if you have some property in your model, or data returned from server, then give that to component like {{comp-one compData=myText}}

Comment: Alright but if I want to sent an action triggered by the template to the component?

Comment: That will be a bad idea, because there will be a tight coupling between outside application and component. Then it will not be a component as such. Can you tell me what exactly you want to achieve, I will tell you how can you do it without creating a tight coupling.

Comment: I have a page with a menu on the top. When the menu element is clicked it slides down. When you click out of the menu then it slides back up. The menu element must be able to be applied to all my applications templates

Comment: You can listen to focusOut event in your component. And then on the basis of jquery selector you can check if $(event.target).closest('.menu-drop-down'). Then you can toggle the view. Otherwise you can have a click event listner on main application which you can check if menu dropdown class is not there , then you can have a toggle property binded to component which shows/hides drop down. I would suggest the former option.

Comment: That sounds like what I want. Can you provide an example please? I would like to see how you structure it